# Rails 3 Migration Alter Float Length/Decimal

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

How would I go about changing the `decimals` and `length` attributes of a float column in my Rails 3 migration file. I have tried the following w/ no success:

```
class IncreaseLatitudeLongitudeFieldLengths < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up

    change_column :skateparks, :latitude, :float, {:length => 15, :decimals => 12}
    change_column :skateparks, :longitude, :float, {:length => 15, :decimals => 12}

  end

  def self.down

    change_column :skateparks, :latitude, :float, {:length => 0, :decimals => 0}
    change_column :skateparks, :longitude, :float, {:length => 0, :decimals => 0}

  end
end
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Personal experience what works best (since MySQL/sqlite sometimes refuses changes to columns): Create a new column, copy the data, delete the old column, rename the new column.

```
# Example for latitude

add_column :skateparks, :latitude2, :decimal, :precision => 15, :scale => 12
execute "UPDATE skateparks SET latitude2 = latitude"
remove_column :skateparks, :latitude
rename_column :skateparks, :latitude2, :latitude
```

EDIT: On the second look `:float, { :length => 15, :decimals => 12 }` seems to be wrong. I assume you meant: `:decimal, :precision => 15, :scale => 12`?

Comment: I tried this but the newly created columns don't seem to be accepting the :length or :decimals options. I end up w/ a float that has length = 0 and decimals = 0

Comment: Updated the answer. I think you messed up float/decimal and the respective settings. Read more [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/TableDefinition.html#method-i-column).

Comment: You're correct. I should of been using :decimal. I've updated my code and everything works now. Thanks!